# Java BST program crashes when I call self implemented search method

Tags: java, search, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to figure out why my program keeps crashing. When I compile in eclipse everything runs smoothly until I select the "search" option in my menu driven BST. I keep getting the error java.lang.NullPointerExcpetion. Part of me feels as if my add method is not working properly when creating new nodes with the assigned values thus returning a null value however I am not sure. Would someone mind taking a look at my code and seeing where I am going wrong? Thanks!
Here is my Stack trace:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*

*at BTree.BTSearch(BTree.java:55)*

*at BTUser.ProcessChoice(BTUser.java:97)*

*at BTUser.main(BTUser.java:26)*

```
public class BTree
{ // opens BTree

// att

BTNode Root;

// code

 public BTNode GetRoot()
 { // open GRo
  return(Root);
 } // closes GRo

 public void SetRoot(BTNode proot)
 { // opens SRo

     Root=proot;
     return;
 } // closes SRo

public void DisplayAll(BTNode current)
{ // opens Disp

     if(current!=null)
     { // opens if

         DisplayAll(current.GetLeft());
         System.out.println(""+current.GetName());
         DisplayAll(current.GetRight());

     } // closes if

        return; 

}  // closes disp


public BTNode BTSearch(BTNode proot, String pName)
{ // open BTSearch

      // locals

      BTNode found;

    // code

    if(proot==null)
    {  //opens if
        found=null;
    } // closes if

    else if(pName.equalsIgnoreCase(proot.GetName()))
        { // opens if

            found=proot;

        } //closes if



   else if(pName.compareToIgnoreCase(proot.GetName())<=0)
       { // opens if

          found=BTSearch(proot.GetLeft(),pName);

       } // closes if




     else
     { // opens 3rd else


         found=BTSearch(proot.GetRight(),pName);

     } // closes 3rd Else

     return(found);      

} // closes BTSearch



     BTNode AddOne(BTNode proot, String pName)
     { // opens add

          //locals

         BTNode Temp;
         Temp = new BTNode(pName);

         // code


         if(proot==null)
         { // opens if



         proot=Temp;
         Temp.SetName(pName);

     } // closes if

     else if(pName.compareToIgnoreCase(proot.GetName())<=0)
         { // opens if

             proot.SetLeft(AddOne(proot.GetLeft(),pName));
         } // closes if          



     else if(pName.compareToIgnoreCase(proot.GetName())>=0)
         { // opens if

             proot.SetRight(AddOne(proot.GetRight(),pName));

         } // opens if


    // } // closes 2nd else

     return(proot);




 } // closes AddOne  






} // closes BTree



public class BTNode
{ // open BTN

   // att

 String Name;
 BTNode LPointer;
 BTNode RPointer;

// code

public BTNode(String pName)
{ // open constructor

 Name=pName;
   return;
} // close constuctor

public String GetName()
{ // opens GN

   return(Name);  

} // closes GN

public void SetName(String pName)
{ // open SetName

  Name = pName;
  return;

} // closes set name


public BTNode GetLeft()
{ // opens GL

return(LPointer);

}// closes GL

public void SetLeft(BTNode pLeft)
{ // opens SL


  LPointer=pLeft;
  return;

} // closes SL

public BTNode GetRight()
{ // opens GR

  return(RPointer);

} // closes GR

public void SetRight(BTNode pRight)
{ // opens SR

  RPointer=pRight;
  return;
} // close SR









 }


 import java.util.Scanner;

public class BTUser
{ // opens BTUser

// code


public static void main (String args[])
{ // opens main

 // locals

 int Choice;
 BTree MyTree;


  MyTree = new BTree(); // instantiate

 do
 { // open post test

  DispMenu();
  Choice=GetChoice();
  ProcessChoice(Choice, MyTree);

 } // close post test
   while(Choice!= 4);
    // methods

  }

    public static void DispMenu()
    { // opens menu



System.out.println("         Please Make a Selection           ");
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("         1. Add Name                       ");
System.out.println("         2. Search a Name                 ");
System.out.println("         3. Display All Names              ");
System.out.println("         4. Quit                           ");



} // closes menu

   public static int GetChoice()
{ // opens getChoice

   // locals

   int lChoice=-1;
   try{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter your Choice ");
   lChoice=keyboard.nextInt();

   }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("invalid choice");
   }
   return(lChoice);


   } // closes get Choice 


   public static String GetName()
   { // opens get name
   // locals
     String prompt;    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name");
    prompt=keyboard.nextLine();

    return(prompt);

   }  // closes get name 

   public static void ProcessChoice(int Choice, BTree MyTree)
   { // opens process choice

   // locals

   String Prompt=null;



   switch (Choice)
            { //open switch

               case 1:Prompt=GetName(); MyTree.SetRoot(MyTree.AddOne(MyTree.GetRoot(),Prompt));
               break;
               case 2: MyTree.BTSearch(MyTree.GetRoot(),Prompt);
               break;
               case 3: MyTree.DisplayAll(MyTree.GetRoot());
               break;
               case 4: System.out.println("\n Have a nice day");
               break;
               default: System.out.println("\n Invalid Choice");
               break;




            }   




   } // closes process choice










    }
```

Comment: You should try debugging, or better yet, writing a test suite. Unit testing will pay off for you in the long term. What's with the comments and the empty lines? keep your code easy to read for your own benefit.

Comment: Thank you everyone I feel like such a idiot, I can't believe I didn't catch that! Guess I just needed another pair of fresh eyes.

Comment: If my answer helped, it would be greatly appreciated if you accepted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by this line of code:
`else if(pName.equalsIgnoreCase(proot.GetName()))`

As is, pName is always null. And therefore, when `pName.equalsIgnoreCase()` is called on a null reference, you get a null pointer exception. Tracing the issue back, I found the bug lies in your switch statement:

```
   switch (Choice)
            { //open switch

               case 1:Prompt=GetName(); MyTree.SetRoot(MyTree.AddOne(MyTree.GetRoot(),Prompt));
               break;
               case 2: MyTree.BTSearch(MyTree.GetRoot(),Prompt);
               break;
               case 3: MyTree.DisplayAll(MyTree.GetRoot());
               break;
               case 4: System.out.println("\n Have a nice day");
               break;
               default: System.out.println("\n Invalid Choice");
               break;




            }
```

You forgot to add the `Prompt=GetName();` line for case 2, and therefore when case 2 (search for name) is chosen, pName is never set and is always null.